# Duda sobre como ordenar un arrayList de forma ascendente

Tags: java

Resulta que realice este codigo, para una tabla de posiciones de una liga, al ejecutarlo, me envia la tabla de forma descendente(por puntos)
Array ordenado por puntos

```
1. Boyaca Chico  5  8  1  2  5  5  11  -6
2. Atletico Bucaramanga  9  8  2  3  3  5  12  -7
3. America De Cali  12  8  3  3  2  11  9  2
4. Alianza Petrolera  13  8  4  1  3  10  8  2
5. Atletico Nacional  15  8  4  3  1  18  11  7
```

lo que quiero realmente, es que dicho codigo me salga al contrario, osea de forma ascendente.
Agradezco cualquier ayuda i sugerencia
Feliz dia

```
    public class Liga {
    static class Equipo implements Comparable<Equipo>{
        public String nombre;
        public int ptos, pj, pg, pe, pp, gf, gc, dfg;

        public Equipo(String nombre, int ptos, int pj, int pg, int pe, int pp, int gf, int gc, int dfg) {
            this.nombre = nombre;
            this.ptos = ptos;
            this.pj = pj;
            this.pg = pg;
            this.pe = pe;
            this.pp = pp;
            this.gf = gf;
            this.gc = gc;
            this.dfg = dfg;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Equipo o) {
            
            if(ptos > o.ptos) {
                return 1; 
            }
            if(ptos < o.ptos) {
                return -1;
            }
            return 0;
        }

     }
     static void imprimirArrayEquipos(Equipo[] array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
            System.out.println((i + 1) + ". " + array[i].nombre + "  " + array[i].ptos + "  " + array[i].pj + "  " 
        + array[i].pg + "  " + array[i].pp + "  " + array[i].pe + "  " + array[i].gf + "  " + array[i].gc + "  "
        + array[i].dfg);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Equipo[] arrayEquipo = new Equipo[5];
        arrayEquipo[0] = new Equipo("Alianza Petrolera", 13, 8, 4, 3, 1, 10, 8, 2); 
        arrayEquipo[1] = new Equipo("America De Cali", 12, 8, 3, 2, 3, 11, 9, 2); 
        arrayEquipo[2] = new Equipo("Atletico Bucaramanga", 9, 8, 2, 3, 3, 5, 12, -7); 
        arrayEquipo[3] = new Equipo("Atletico Nacional", 15, 8, 4, 1, 3, 18, 11, 7); 
        arrayEquipo[4] = new Equipo("Boyaca Chico", 5, 8, 1, 5, 2, 5, 11, -6); 
        
        
        System.out.println("pos nombre ptos pj pe pp gf gc dfg");
        System.out.println("Array sin ordenar");
        imprimirArrayEquipos(arrayEquipo);
        
        Arrays.sort(arrayEquipo);
        System.out.println("Array ordenado por puntos");
        imprimirArrayEquipos(arrayEquipo);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: public int compareTo(Equipo o) {

         if(ptos > o.ptos) {
             return -1; 
         }
         if(ptos < o.ptos) {
             return 1;
         }
         return 0;
     }

Comment: @toto ponelo como respuesta porfa...

Comment: Al implementar Comparable creaste una forma de comparar dos equipos. Cambia la implementación del método compareTo y cambiarás el orden. Otra opción es usar un Comparator externo

Comment: Complicas la implementación del `compareTo`, solo basta con colocar esto: `return ptos-o.ptos; `, con eso puedes ordenar de forma ascendente.

Comment: Por favor agrega la versión de java también, por que esto puede ser resuelto con expresiones lambda(**java8+**) y realizar lo directo sin usar el **override**

Answer (score 1):

Explicación antes de mostrar el ejemplo:

Método compareTo está disponible para todos los objetos no primitivos de Java.
Consiste en lo siguiente: si el de la izquierda es mayor al de la derecha devuelve 1, si el de la izquierda es menor que el de la derecha devuelve -1 y si son iguales devuelve 0.

Ejemplo:

```
Integer v1 = 1;
Integer v2 = 2;
System.out.println(v1.compareTo(v2));
//El resultado por consola es -1. porque v1 es menor a v2

 v1 = 2;
 v2 = 1;
System.out.println(v1.compareTo(v2));
//El resultado por consola es 1 poruqe v1 es mayor a v2.

 v1 = 2;
 v2 = 2;
System.out.println(v1.compareTo(v2));
```

Esa es la lógica que utiliza para ordenar de forma ASCENDENTE.
Para que ordene de forma DESCENDENTE debes retornar lo opuesto, es decir, si A > B debes decirle que B es mayor A enviando -1 o cambiando el orden de la comparación, es decir B > A retorno 1.

Vamos con tu ejemplo:

```
 public int compareTo(Equipo o) { 
             
              Integer a = this.ptos;
              Integer b = o.ptos;
              //ORDEN ASCENDENTE:
              //return a.compareTo(b);
              
              //ORDEN DESCENDENTE
              return b.compareTo(a);
              //o tambien puede ser:
              // return a.compareTo(b)*-1;
            }
```

Comment: Te animas a explicar un poco mas? tipo, compareto devuelve esto o esto, y hace que se ordene de tal forma.. si invertimos el orden.. bla....